# Generic T get type from class

Tags: c#, generics

How can I get this to work? var x  = error type or namespace name expected.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person j = new John();
        var t = j.GetType();
        var x = new List<t>();
    }
}

class John : Person
{

}

class Person
{
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Because generics aren't dynamic. They're a compile-time .NET type feature, not a runtime feature.

Comment: If you REALLY want, you can do it using reflection, but it's a pain to create the List and to use the list (unless you cast it to one of the non-generic interfaces it has, like `IEnumerable`).

Comment: @xantos - not really that hard to create and use. See my answer.

Comment: @Preet You beat me of 1m30 you know, I was writing nearly the same piece of code. And you forgot an `a` in my name :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to use generics like that. All type parameters of generic classes and functions have to be known at compile time (i.e. they have to be hardcoded), while in your case the result of `j.GetType()` can only be known at run time.

Generics are designed to provide compile-type safety, so this restriction cannot be lifted. It can be worked around in some cases, e.g. you *can* call a generic method with a type parameter that is only known at compile time using Reflection, but this is generally something you should avoid if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but you have to use reflection to do so.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person j = new John();
        var t = j.GetType();
        Type genType = Type.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(List<>) });
        IList x =  (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(genType, t);        
    }
```

or really simply:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type genType = Type.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { typeof(List<>) });
        IList x =  (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(genType, typeof(John)); 
    }
```

You'll have to use the [IList Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) as you need to add stuff to the list

Comment: The problem with this is that once you cross the border of Reflection-land, there's no going back. You can't use the type you constructed with static code.

Comment: @jon - what do you mean? you can cast that object to a List<John> as that's what it is.

Comment: If you cast it to `List<Person>` you need to hardcode the cast (including the type) -- so what benefit did you get from reflecting? As xanatos says, *in this specific case* you can cast to `IList` and get *some* functionality, but you are still stuck with `object` instead of `Person` instances. In the general case, the object is totally unusable by code except if you continue with reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Because generics must be known at compile time. In `List<T>`, T must be a constant type, for example `List<Person>`.